# Why was my question regarding migration from G-Suite to Office 365 closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I wrote the following question: https://superuser.com/questions/1715257/migrate-g-suite-to-office-365 - why was this closed?

According to the [Super User Tour](https://superuser.com/tour)

> Super User is a question and answer site for computer enthusiasts and power users. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about computer software or hardware.

- **G-Suite** is a software as a service suite offered to businesses AND individuals.
- **Office 365** is a software as a service suite offered to businesses AND individuals.

As an individual - not in the realm of g-suite/office SaaS administration and usage, I asked a question about migration from one to the other.  My question was closed with no explanation except the canned response of "off topic".

Since it was closed the Q&A commenced in comments.  I was told the following:

1. **Office 365 Personal/Family does NOT support domains.**  This is FALSE information.  I have since learned it does support domains.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/get-a-personalized-email-address-in-microsoft-365-75416a58-b225-4c02-8c07-8979403b427b?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us addresses using your own domain.  Definitely something a power user would do.  In fact, it is geared for most non-tech Joes to be able to do this so this falls off the bottom of the Power User scale.
2. **Office 365 Family only supports 5 people max.**  This is FALSE information.  I already knew it supported 6 - the magic number I need for my scenario.  Completely documented here:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/buy/compare-all-microsoft-365-products#

Can anyone give a clear explanation why this was closed, or answer my inquiry of what site I should go to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the tour page you quoted:

Do not ask about:

...

- Websites or web services like Google, Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress

[image]

Asking about the Office 365 *programs* would likely be on topic, but not as the question is now (the service or the online aspect of it)

Comment: hmmm.  I do not read the meaning quite the same way you do - but fair enough.  **Where** does one go to get questions answered about migrating SaaS apps?

Comment: Webapps. Question probably needs a bit more fleshing out, but I've migrated it there. In a professional level, Server Fault might work as well, but this is personal, and moving it there would be more frustration

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - thank you!  And I agree.  Main reason I chose here instead of Server Fault.  Lesson learned...

Comment: Marked as the answer - as the answer is actually in the comments here.

Comment: I am looking around webapps.  I am not hopeful the question will be answered.  I've gone through 150+ open questions and they boil down to email rules, calcs in spreadsheets, my FB account was stolen, etc.  <sigh/>

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't control the other sites and what they consider on topic. WebApps would be the closest, so I'd suggest trying it there.

Comment: Just so you know - every stack I've tried has rejected this question.  I have finally figured it out myself so there is that.